# Grails password encrypt with rsa

Tags: java, grails, rsa, grails-2.0, password-encryption

I want to create a module called User. This module consists of Name, username, phoneNo, and password. I want to encrypt and decreypt the password using RSA algorythm.

this is my RSA.Java

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

/**
 * Simple RSA public key encryption algorithm implementation.
 */

public class RSA {
  private BigInteger n, d, e;

  private int bitlen = 1024;

  /** Create an instance that can encrypt using someone elses public key. */
  public RSA(BigInteger newn, BigInteger newe) {
    n = newn;
    e = newe;
  }

  /** Create an instance that can both encrypt and decrypt. */
  public RSA(int bits) {
    bitlen = bits;
    SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
    BigInteger p = new BigInteger(bitlen / 2, 100, r);
    BigInteger q = new BigInteger(bitlen / 2, 100, r);

    n = p.multiply(q);
    BigInteger m = (p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));

    e = new BigInteger("3");
    while (m.gcd(e).intValue() > 1) {
      e = e.add(new BigInteger("2"));
    }
    d = e.modInverse(m);
  }

  /** Encrypt the given plaintext message. */
  public synchronized String encrypt(String message) {
    return (new BigInteger(message.getBytes())).modPow(e, n).toString();
  }

  /** Encrypt the given plaintext message. */
  public synchronized BigInteger encrypt(BigInteger message) {
    return message.modPow(e, n);
  }

  /** Decrypt the given ciphertext message. */
  public synchronized String decrypt(String message) {
    return new String((new BigInteger(message)).modPow(d, n).toByteArray());
  }

  /** Decrypt the given ciphertext message. */
  public synchronized BigInteger decrypt(BigInteger message) {
    return message.modPow(d, n);
  }

  /** Generate a new public and private key set. */
  public synchronized void generateKeys() {
    SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
    BigInteger p = new BigInteger(bitlen / 2, 100, r);
    BigInteger q = new BigInteger(bitlen / 2, 100, r);
    n = p.multiply(q);
    BigInteger m = (p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(q
        .subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
    e = new BigInteger("3");
    while (m.gcd(e).intValue() > 1) {
      e = e.add(new BigInteger("2"));
    }
    d = e.modInverse(m);
  }

  /** Return the modulus. */
  public synchronized BigInteger getN() {
    return n;
  }

  /** Return the public key. */
  public synchronized BigInteger getE() {
    return e;
  }
}
```

This is my domain User.groovy :

```
class User{

    String name
    String username
    String phoneNo
    String password

}
```

This is my UserController.groovy : (save and update )

```
class UserController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

    def index = {
        redirect(action: "list", params: params)
    }

    def save = {
        def userInstance = new User(params)
        if (userInstance .save(flush: true)) {
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), userInstance .id])}"
            redirect(action: "show", id: userInstance .id)
        }
        else {
            render(view: "create", model: [userInstance : userInstance ])
        }
    }


    def edit = {
        def userInstance = User.get(params.id)
        if (!userInstance ) {
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), params.id])}"
            redirect(action: "list")
        }
        else {
            return [userInstance : userInstance ]
        }
    }

    def update = {
        def userInstance = User.get(params.id)
        if (userInstance ) {
            if (params.version) {
                def version = params.version.toLong()
                if (userInstance .version > version) {

                    userInstance .errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure", [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User')] as Object[], "Another user has updated this User while you were editing")
                    render(view: "edit", model: [userInstance : userInstance ])
                    return
                }
            }
            userInstance .properties = params
            if (!userInstance .hasErrors() && userInstance .save(flush: true)) {
                flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), userInstance .id])}"
                redirect(action: "show", id: userInstance .id)
            }
            else {
                render(view: "edit", model: [userInstance : userInstance ])
            }
        }
        else {
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), params.id])}"
            redirect(action: "list")
        }
    }
}
```

What must I add in my save and edit controller so when I save the form the password encrypted then when I'll edit the form the password will be decrypted? please help me, because I'm new in Java and grails, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [SpringSecurity Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core), you can use `beforeInsert` and `beforeUpdate` event to do transformation on your password. In those method implement your encryption.

```
class User {

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        password blank: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the use of account expired? according to the script there's Role, that's mean i must add the new user role domain? isn't it?

Comment: This is an example of Spring Security core user object, if you are rolling your own security, you might not need it. I put this up here so you can see how beforeInsert and beforeUpdate are being used. As you can see they encodePassword before insert and when the records is being updated.